# jquery using json object

Tags: javascript, jquery

**script.js**

```
$('#loginform').submit(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/accounts/login/ajax/",
        data:$('#loginform').serialize(),
        success: function(msg){
            var msg = msg;
            msg = JSON.parse(msg);
            $('#messagestatus').html('');
            if(msg.username != null){
                $('#messagestatus').append(msg.username);
            }
            if(msg.password != null){
                $('#messagestatus').append(msg.password);
            }
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();             
});
```

**returned object**

```
{'username':['Required'],'password':['Required']}
```

When I am using `JSON.parse` and I am alerting, it's showing the correct error, but when I am appending it to the `messagestatus` div its not responding, please help .

Comment: What's with the `var msg = msg;`?

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ complains about `{'username':['Required'],'password':['Required']}` not being valid JSON. It comes back with `Parse error on line 1: {    'username': [      -----^Expecting 'STRING', '}'` Replace the `'` with `"` and the JSON will be valid. You still got the issue though of password and username values being arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Your username and password are arrays in your json.Either make it that your json looks like

```
    {'username':'Required','password':'Required'}
```

or change your script:

```
    if(msg.username.length > 0)
    {
       $('#messagestatus').text(msg.username[0]);
    }
    if(msg.password.length > 0)
    {
       $('#messagestatus').text(msg.password[0]);
    }
```

Comment: but how do i check if username exists or not ??

Comment: add `if ( typeof msg.username != 'undefined' )` before the first if, and `if ( typeof msg.password != 'undefined')` before the second if.

Answer (score 1):

Might be significant, might not be, but your json object actually consists of sub-arrays:

```
{'username':['Required'],'password':['Required']}
            ^----------^            ^----------^
```

meaning that the decoded data structure in JS would actually be

```
obj['username'][0]   and        obj['password'][0]
```

Comment: It also has `'` instead of `"` around its keys.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, parameters do not need to be redeclared in their function.

then, to parse your json using $.parseJSON() :

```
msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
```

Your JSON contains arrays, use msg["username"][0] to access the first string and not the full array.

And I would put e.preventDefault(); as first statement before AJAX.

And .html('') => .empty() but it's the same result.